# AEM/CQ: Conditional CSS class on decoration tag

Tags: javascript, aem

How can I dynamically set a CSS class on the wrapping decoration tag of an AEM6 Sightly component?

I cannot set this CSS class on the component as it depends on the instance of the component, and I can't set it on the resource as the resource can be rendered on multiple pages and the CSS class differs depending on which page it is on.

I've tried the following 3 techniques inside the JavaScript Use-API with no success:

```
componentContext.getCssClassNames().add('test-class-1');
component.getHtmlTagAttributes().set('class', 'test-class-2');//throws an exception
currentNode.setProperty('cq:cssClass', 'test-class-3');
```

Answer (score 9):

The decoration tag is added by a filter (namely the `WCMComponentFilter`) before the component is actually rendered, so it isn't possible to change it inside the component code. In order to use some logic to dynamically set a CSS class on this decorator, you need to create a custom filter, that will run before the `WCMComponentFilter` and set appropriate properties to the `IncludeOptions` attribute.

Following filter adds `my-class` to all carousel components under `/content/geometrixx/en`.

```
@SlingFilter(scope = SlingFilterScope.COMPONENT, order = -300)
public class DecoratorFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        boolean addClass = false;
        if (request instanceof SlingHttpServletRequest) {
            final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
            final Resource resource = slingRequest.getResource();
            final String resourceType = resource.getResourceType();
            final String resourcePath = resource.getPath();

            // put any custom logic here, eg.:
            addClass = "foundation/components/carousel".equals(resourceType)
                    && resourcePath.startsWith("/content/geometrixx/en");
        }
        if (addClass) {
            final IncludeOptions options = IncludeOptions.getOptions(request, true);
            options.getCssClassNames().add("my-class");
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Actually used this today and works great! Only one note (tested on AEM 6.3.2):  in our case we wanted to add our class before executing the WCMComponentFilter. The "order" should then be above 200 since WCMComponentFilter has rank 200. A higher rank means its executed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The Correct way to do is using **cq:htmlTag**. 
Create a unstructured node under your component with name `cq:htmlTag`

Add a property to it "class" of type "String" and the value being "myclass" the class you want to add to your component's wrapper/decorator div.

Refer links:

1) [Wrapper Div Manipulation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/ComponentDiv.html)

2) [Best link to understand this](http://www.codermag.net/2016/02/remove-component-wrapper-divs-in-cqaem.html)