# How can I stop CQ 5.5 wrapping iparsys content in <div class="iparys_inherited">?

Tags: jsp, jstl, aem

I’m working on a CQ 5.5 site. On our home page, I’m using an iparsys to inherit navigation from our root page:

```
<cq:include path="navigation" resourceType="foundation/components/iparsys" />
```

When I view the home page on our publish server, the navigation is rendered wrapped in a `<div>` with a class of “`iparys_inherited`”:

(Please note: this is not a typo on my part, this is the exact HTML we’re seeing.)

```
<div class="iparys_inherited"><!-- iparsys content appears here --></div>
```

We include a global JSP file in all our pages that, amongst other things, calls `com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext.setDefaultDecorationTagName` to turn off decoration tags in publish mode:

```
componentContext.setDefaultDecorationTagName("");
```

But this seems to have no effect on the `iparys_inherited` `<div>`.

Is there a way to stop this wrapper `<div>` being rendered?

Comment: If you use an iParsys on Geometrixx demo site, does it correctly display a wrapper of `iparsys_inherited` or does it still display `iparys_inherited`? Have you overlaid any of the foundation components that could be affecting this?

Answer (score 1):

part of a solution is described in

[How to use cq:noDecorator property in cq5 , can the default 'div' tag be changed to other block tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415626/how-to-use-cqnodecorator-property-in-cq5-can-the-default-div-tag-be-changed)

This clarifies how for the next level of inclusion the edit context can be enforced to the same edit context as the parent (and therefore eliminate the decoration that is added to attach editing UI.

If you want to enforce this for all inclusions without adding the codesnippet over and over you can utilize a Sling Filter with Scope Component to "reset" this flag after it was evaluated for decoration (which is done itself in the filter com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter) - that way you should be able to enforce the same edit context for the complete inclusion tree.